# Oversampling a signal

Tags: sampling, downsampling, resampling

I’ve built a circuit with an analogue sensor (70 Hz bandwidth) connected to a 24 bit ADC, which is oversampling the signal at 10 kHz. Nyquist sampling theorem implies I should sample by at least 140 Hz to reconstruct the signal.

Currently (if I’ve understood [oversampling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling) correctly) I’m oversampling by a factor of $N = \frac{10000-140}{140} = 70$. As the minimum sampling frequency is the Nyquist rate, and oversampling is a factor $N$ times this minimum rate. My questions are:

- Does this oversampling only reduce the noise introduced from the output of the analogue sensor (given the low bandwidth of the sensor) to the end of the ADC process?
- How much can I reduce the oversampling (which introduces a processor overhead) by for a negligible increase in the amount of noise to the signal?
- Could I do anything else to reduce the amount of oversampling, e.g increase the ADC resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that same page you link to:

> A signal is said to be oversampled by a factor of N if it is sampled at N times the Nyquist rate.

So, you're sampling at $1\cdot10^4\,\text{Hz}$, that's $N=\frac{10^4}{140}\approx 71$; no need to subtract anything.

> Does this oversampling only reduce the noise introduced from the output of the analogue sensor (given the low bandwidth of the sensor) to the end of the ADC process?

[Oversampling alone doesn't reduce noise](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/68082/13320). It's what you do afterwards with the signal. Oversampling *can be necessary* to e.g. to be able to filter out the noise that can be shaped to your advantage.

> How much can I reduce the oversampling (which introduces a processor overhead) by for a negligible increase in the amount of noise to the signal?

You need to define "negligible"; also, you need to think about the noise is distributed in frequency domain during your sampling process; there's no general answer.

> Could I do anything else to reduce the amount of oversampling, e.g increase the ADC resolution?

I'm confused: The only way to reduce oversampling is to reduce the sampling rate.

Maybe you mean

> to reduce the **necessary** amount of oversampling

Well, that fully depends on your signal, and what you want to do with it, and you forgot to tell us about either!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The sampling rate at 10K is the total sampling rate I’m reading the ADC, my rationale for subtracting the nyquist rate from it was that if N is the over sample rate then I would have thought that N = 0 would imply no oversampling i.e. only sampling at 140Hz. But I could be wrong! You’re right I missed it from my original question that I’m oversampling and then averaging (mean) the data to reduce noise - with this in mind does my original question make more sense? Also I was hoping to reduce the necessary oversampling so there is max increase of 2% noise on the signal.

Comment: yes, you're wrong; it's a factor, not an additional factor, so the definition of the wikipedia article is clear. But that really doesn't matter much here, does it? I

Comment: I'm still confused what you mean with "reduce oversampling", could you elaborate?

Comment: So if I made the assumption that at N = 71 the noise equalled 0 how much could I reduced the oversampling too e.g N = 65, for the noise to increase by 2%?

Comment: Also given I’m oversampling and averaging a much lower bandwidth signal is this going to reduce noise introduced from the sensor and ADC or is it just going to reduce noise from the ADC?

Comment: @Joe again, that can't be said without knowing the noise spectral density.